# Operator precedence of nullish coalescing and ternary

Tags: javascript, operators

Can someone explain why `result` evaluates to `20` in this statement?

```js
let result = 10 ?? true ? 20 : 30;
```

Given nullish coalescing evalutes the statement in a left-to-right manner and is of higher [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than a ternary operator, why is it safe to not assume that `result` should be `10`?

Note: if a grouping operator is added, then `result` is `10`.

```js
let result = 10 ?? (true ? 20 : 30);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: _"why is it safe"_ You gave the answer yourself: _"nullish coalescing evalutes the statement in a left-to-right manner and is of higher precedence than a ternary operator"_. Which means that your first expression is equivalent to `(10 ?? true) ? 20 : 30`. Just like `*` is of higher precedence than `+`: `1 * 2 + 3 === (1 * 2) + 3`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I understand it, a [nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) has a higher [operator presedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than a [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), so it should execute first.

(The [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table) say that `??` operator has an operator precedence score of 5, while `... ? ... : ...`  has a score of 4.)

So

```js
let result = 10 ?? true ? 20 : 30;
```

basically evaluates to

```js
let result = (10 ?? true) ? 20 : 30; // => 10 ? 20 : 30
```

And given that 10 is a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value, it (`10 ? 20 : 30`) evaluates to 20

#### Extra details

You may notice that there is an *"Associativity"* column in the [JavaScript table of operator presedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table).

And you may wonder if it plays a role in this case. But the answer to that seems to be that *it doesn't*. And that's stated in the following quote (from the docs):

> The difference in *associativity comes into play when there are multiple operators of the same precedence*.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#precedence_and_associativity)

Comment: ah, makes sense now—thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @IliasT Glad it helped. No problem! ^__^

Answer (score 0):

As stated above in blex's comment, the statement simply reduces the coalescing operation to the value 10, then evaluates 10 ? 20 : 30. Since 10 is a truthy value, the ternary operation here will return the true case, which is 20.

Answer (score 0):

There will be no case where you combine nullish coalescing and ternary. Have a look at this example:

```
a ?? false ? 'foo' : 'bar'
```

If `a` is truthy, then `a` is picked, and `'foo'` is obviously returned.
If `a` is nullish, i.e. `null, undefined`, then `false` is picked, and `'bar'` is returned.
If `a` is of other falsy values, i.e. `'', 0, false`, then `a` is picked. However, `a` is still falsy in the perspective of the ternary, therefore `'bar'` is returned.
If you want to bring nullish check to a conditional statement, instead use:

```
a != null ? 'foo' : 'bar' // a is not null or undefined
!a && a != null ? 'bar' : 'foo' // a is not '', 0, or false. Does anyone really use this one?
```